# Html header across screen width

Tags: html

I have been playing around with basic html coding, and I can't get the header to run across the entire screen width

```
<div id="header" style=" position:fixed;  background-color: #0099CC; width=100%">
    <h1 style="float: left; color: black">Hello</h1>
    <div style="float: right; padding: 2.5em 5em;"> 
    <a href="teamassignment">Blah Blah</a>
    <a href="logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note: I do not want to use CSS. I can do this through CSS perfectly fine, but I've been fiddling with html and just isn't sure why the same properties don't apply when I use style in html coding.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJSsP/

Comment: The style tag is CSS as well.

Comment: WHY are you not wanting to use CSS? That's what it's for, styling HTML...

Comment: If you don't want to use CSS, why is about 50% of the code you have shared in the question CSS?

Comment: Oh no. I am using CSS in production. This is something that's been bothering me, cause I was always taught CSS, and I wanted to see why using html is inefficient, and how to do it.

Comment: @naddnan You still do not understand that you are not styling it with HTML. You are doing it with inline CSS styles.

Comment: you itself using inline css and what is "CSS in production" ?? can you explain it?

Comment: @naddnan styling using only html is bad, because you cannot do what are you trying to do without CSS :) a part from, maybe, using tables and some deprecated attributes.. Seriously, don't do that, it's just part of the past..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
display: block;
```

?

`"width=100%"` is NOT a valid CSS rule, `width: 100%;` is (but you won't need it in this example)

This should do the job:

```
<div id="header" style=" position:fixed;  background-color: #0099CC; display: block;">
```

By the way, the `style=""` attribute **does** define CSS rules to be associated with the element..

### Update

I see you're using `float: left`: elements with `float` use a special positioning system that doesn't allow them to use `display` property..

Instead, you should use `float: right` on the links and leave the title alone.

### Example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJSsP/5/

or, the bare minimum you need, for sake of clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/WJSsP/6/

Answer (score 3):

width=100%"

should be

width:100%"

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the Header will only be the width of the content so without CSS to alter the default, it will not expand.

Answer (score 0):

Change "width=100%" to "width:100%".

Sometimes it really is that simple :)